# Comment expliquez-vous l'utilisation de « y » dans l'expression « y attaché » ?

Tags: sens, pronoms, histoire, droit-et-justice

J'ai du mal a comprendre cette phrase à cause du « y » :

> Tel que ledit BIEN existe, s’étend, se poursuit et comporte, avec
> toutes ses aisances, dépendances et immeubles par destination,
> servitudes et mitoyennetés, tous droits et facultés quelconques y
> attachées, sans exception ni réserve, autres que celles pouvant être
> le cas échéant relatées aux présentes.

Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'éclairer à ce propos?

Moi j'aurais écrit « ci-attachées ».

---

*Note pour répondre à Stéphane: la phrase vient d'un acte notarié de vente/achat d'immobilier.*

Comment: Peux-tu mentionner d'où provient cet extrait dans ta question ?

Comment: Je me permets de répondre, sans en être mandaté : c'est une formule usuelle dans tous les actes notariés de vente donc d'achat immobilier, lourdement répétitive pour ne laisser aucune échappatoire, et disent les mauvaises langues, datant du temps où les droits sur les actes étaient payés à la ligne.

Comment: Ceci peut servir à soi-même : http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1237948

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le notaire a raison : "y" est une ancienne déclinaison de "ci", représentant l'*attribution*.

En décomposant, il faut comprendre "**à ci** attachés", soit en français moderne "attachés **à** celui-ci", et l'on ne pourrait omettre le "à".

Remarques :

- malgré son nom, "y" n'est aucunement grec ; le datif du latin *is* = ce est *ibi*, et par contraction s'écrit "y" représentant "*ii*".
- Il reste quelques traces de déclinaison en français moderne : "il me dit" = "il dit à je".
- "y" est un mot très difficile, vu ses nombreuses natures et fonctions.

Comment: Une source qui confirme cela ?

Comment: Je réponds généralement de mémoire, et spontanément, mais ai donc vérifié : n'importe quelle grammaire latine (comme Cart) donne pour datif de "is", en latin classique : "ei"; le dictionnaire étymologique de Dauzat signale qu'en bas-latin il était devenu "ibi" (je soupçonne : sous l'influence de "tibi", datif de "tu") ; le Littré (p 2554-5 de mon édition originelle) confirme. Nota : un commentaire, même nominatif, ne m'est jamais notifié ; ce n'est que parce que je m'étonnais de ne pas avoir de réponse que j'ai relu l'ensemble ; je ne le fais d'ordinaire que lorsque j'ai eu des mauvais points.

Comment: C'est surtout le fait que *y* est issu de cette contraction qu'il me semble important de vérifier.