# Que signifient « aisance » et « servitude » dans un texte juridique ?

Tags: sens, droit-et-justice

> Tel que ledit BIEN existe, s’étend, se poursuit et comporte, avec
>   toutes ses **aisances**, dépendances et immeubles par destination,
>   **servitudes** et mitoyennetés, tous droits et facultés quelconques y
>   attachées, sans exception ni réserve, autres que celles pouvant être
>   le cas échéant relatées aux présentes.

Reposant sur [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/comment-expliquez-vous-lutilisation-de-y-dans-lexpression-y-attache), prière d'en faire ressortir les points communs et les divergences ? Je me suis informé [ici](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1405262) et [là](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1405262), mais je reste désemparé car les deux définitions ci-dessous me paraissent identiques.

[Aisance](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/aisance), Terme de jurisprudence:

> Servitude, commodité, service qu'un voisin retire d'un autre en vertu de convention ou de prescription.

[Servitude](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/servitude), Terme de droit:

> Assujétissement imposé à un champ, à une maison, etc. par lequel le propriétaire est obligé d'y souffrir certaines charges, comme l'écoulement des eaux, un passage, une vue, etc.

Comment: Sauf si tu en as un besoin fort, je te déconseille de te servir de textes juridiques pour apprendre le français, c'est un jargon séparé de l'usage normal, dans le vocabulaire et dans le style.  La redondance et le choix de tournures et d'acceptions désuettes ailleurs en font partie.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Je vous remercie de vos conseils. Je pose cette question car il s'est trouvé que je trouve cet extrait juridique par hasard. Au demeurant, je voudrais m'étaler sur toutes les sortes des textes et prendrai garde du jargon atypique des œuvres juridiques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si je comprends bien (je ne suis pas juriste, et ces mots ne sont pas du vocabulaire courant) :

- Une aisance est un droit associé au bien concerné qui affecte un autre bien.
- Une servitude est un droit associé à un autre bien qui affecte le bien concerné.

En d'autres termes, une aisance est positive alors qu'une servitude est négative. Dans les deux cas, il s'agit d'une règle qui concerne deux biens (deux propriétés immobilières), qui représente un avantage d'un côté (aisance) et une contrainte de l'autre (servitude).

Par exemple, si mon voisin a le droit de passer par mon jardin pour sortir sa voiture, c'est une aisance associée à la propriété du voisin, et une servitude associée à ma propriété.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant. Pour clarifier, pourriez-vous expliciter `le bien concerné` et `l'autre bien` dans votre exemple ? Veuillez riposter dans votre reponse propre et non pas en tant que commentaire.

Comment: @LePressentiment Un *bien* (dans le sens utilisé ici), c'est ce que quelqu'un possède. Ici, il s'agit d'un *bien immobilier* (un terrain, une maison, un appartement, …). Dans l'exemple, le bien est un terrain qui est ma propriété. P.S. pas *riposter*, mais *répondre*. Je ne vois pas quoi ajouter à la réponse, j'ai l'impression que tu t'es juste trompé sur le sens de *bien*.

Comment: Plussoyé. Je tiens à vous exprimer ma gratitude pour votre nouveau paragraphe pénultième. Je comprends mieux, or pourriez-vous expliciter `le bien concerné` et `l'autre bien` dans votre réponse? Quel désigne `le droit de passer par mon jardin` et quel se rapporte à `sortir sa voiture` ?

Comment: @LePressentiment Je ne comprends pas pourquoi tu coupe « le droit de passer par mon jardin pour sortir sa voiture » au milieu. Si tu considères mon jardin (donc le « bien concerné » est mon jardin, ou plus exactement le terrain où se situe mon jardin), ce droit est une servitude. Si tu considères le terrain du voisin (donc le bien concerné est son terrain), ce droit est une aisance.

Comment: À votre bon cœur ! Je l'ai coupée au milieu car votre réponse spécifie `un bien concerné` et `un autre bien,` qui m’apparaissent être 2 biens/bidules séparés. SVP, pourriez-vous unir tous vos commentaires et les déplacer dans votre réponse ladite ?

Comment: C'est essentiellement une clause de style dans la section désignant le bien faisant l'objet d'un transfert de propriété. Seule la servitude apparaît au C.C. Le terme _fonds dominant/servant_ est sans doute plus utile pour nommer l'aspect positif/négatif dont tu parles ; le fonds est grevé au profit d'un autre fonds. Dans le contexte où on identifie un immeuble particulier pour fins de transfert, on s'intéresse à tout ce qui le grève, qui lui accroît, essentiellement à l'assiette du droit qui n'est pas limitée d'entrée de jeu. Aisance rappelle _easements_, concept apparenté en droit anglais.